# Setting size of flipview the same as image inside

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, flipview

I have a `flipview` and when I try to remove `height` property, `flipview` becomes much more taller than images. So I want a flipview that will be as tall as images inside.

```
    <FlipView x:Name="FlipView" MaxHeight="400" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=Images}">
        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=URL}" Stretch="Uniform">
            </DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        <FlipView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemsPanel>
    </FlipView>
```

How can I set `height` of the flipview the same as the first image inside?

Comment: why as the _first_ image?

Comment: I'm creating RSS reader, so the first image should cover the whole flipview

Comment: Then you would have to add a new property like "FirstImageHeight" to the `ViewModel` and set its value at run time (by retrieving the actual height of the first image), and bind the flipview's Height to this property.

Comment: I tried, but image is inside `datatemplate`, so I'm not sure how to do this

Comment: How about `<FlipView Height="{Binding FirstImageHeight}" ...`? Set the height of the FlipView, the image inside the template would take the height of the FilpView control.